# Can I extend my Schengen visa from France in Italy?

Tags: schengen, us-citizens, visa-extensions

I'm a USA citizen with a six-month visa for France. Can I now move to Italy and extend my Schengen visa in Italy?

Comment: what category of visa do you currently hold? D?

Comment: It's possible in theory but unlikely. In addition to the category of your current visa, the answer depends on the basis of your potential extension in Italy.

Comment: I have a D visa.  The extension is to retire in Italy. So if I extend my D visa in France I can move to Italy because its part of the Schengen?

Answer (score 3):

- As a US citizen, you can stay visa free in the Schengen area for 90 days out of every 180 days. You need a national (D) visa for any longer stay.
- Days spent in the nation which granted your D visa do not count against the 90-day limit. If you were in France for most of the last six months, you probably have some visa-free days left.
- You cannot extend your **French** visa in Italy. You can in principle apply for a new **Italian** D visa. For details on that, ask in [Expatriates Stack Exchange](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/).